# How to export reference of central variable

Tags: javascript, node.js, sockets, hapi.js

I'm using Hapi.

I'm also using NES client to connect to another node instance. In order to access this socket from the routes, I attach it to the server variable like so:

```
exports = async () => {
  //api
  var server = new Hapi.Server({
    host: process.env.WEB_HOST || '127.0.0.1',
    port: process.env.WEB_PORT || '8080'
  });

  // register plugins
  await server.register(plugins);

  // add routes
  await routes(server);

  server.socket = new Socket(identifier); // uses NES

  return server;
}
```

I want to access the socket from a library file. How do I do this without having to pass it the server variable each time? When I try to `module.exports` the server, it never gives me a reference, only a version of the variable at the time it was exported.

Comment: You pass the variable each time it is needed or you put it into some state that the library has access to.  node.js modularity and the advantages that that modularity offers discourages you from using global variables for state like this.  We would have to see more code (including the relevant library functions that want to use  the `server` variable) to have a more specific recommendation.

Comment: I might also mention that because you've made your export function be `async`, it does not directly return your `server` variable.  Instead, it returns a promise that you have to use `.then()` or `await` with to get the server value out of that promise.  It appears that this was your choice.  The `server` variable is available synchronously, but you decided to have your exported function return a promise that tracks when other activities related to that server are done.

Comment: How do you load/use this "library file"? My guess is: this "library file" should be [registered](https://hapijs.com/api#server.register()) as a server plugin, which receives a reference to `server` - so you can use it at runtime. As a side note, you may want to bind your socket to `server.options.app`, since [that's what it's made for](https://hapijs.com/api#server.options.app). ;)

Answer (score 0):

Have you tried server.decorate. **If I understood correctly**, you want to access your socket variable from routes. Why not just create basic plugin and create your socket instance and pass that into server object. For example;

```
exports.plugin = {
    async register(server, options) {                 
        server.decorate('server', 'socketConn', new Socket(identifier));
    },
    name: 'socket-connection'
};
```

and in your routes you can access this variable as `request.server.socketConn`.